# Permalink slug no longer editable when using post_type_link filter

Tags: permalinks, filters

I want to customize the output of the permalink for a custom post type, but I want the permalink to still be editable when editing a post. I'm using the `post_type_link` filter:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', function( $post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample ) {
    if ( 'job' == $post->post_type ) {
        $post_link = 'http://localhost:8888/testsite/job/' . $post->post_name . '/';
    }
    return $post_link;
}, 10, 4 );
```

When this filter is active, it no longer shows the "Edit" button next to the permalink when editing the post. Even if I remove the custom permalink stuff and only have `return $post_link;` it still disables editing of the permalink.

How can I customize the output and still keep the permalink editable?

Comment: If the post type slug is `job`, then the default permalink structure should be `job/<post slug>`, so why are you manually customizing it via that filter?

Comment: @SallyCJ this is just a test to get it working first, then I'll customize the URL once editing of the slug is working. Sorry, should've mentioned that in the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I customize the output and still keep the permalink editable?

The following worked for me:

```php
$post_link = home_url( '/job/' . ( $leavename ? '%postname%' : $post->post_name ) . '/' );
```

I.e. If the `$leavename` is `true`, use `%postname%` in the URL. Otherwise, you may then use the actual post name/slug, i.e. the value of the `$post->post_name`.

Additionally, I suggest you to use `home_url()` than hard-coding the site URL into the permalink. :)

And I presume you will or have already setup the rewrite rules for the permalinks (`/job/<post slug>/` in the above example)?

> Even if I remove the custom permalink stuff and only have `return $post_link;` it still disables editing of the permalink.

I'm not getting that issue, so it's probably a theme/plugin conflict on your site — try deactivating plugins and enable them back one at a time until you've found the culprit.

Comment: That worked great! Thanks!

Comment: This also fixed my issue. Thank you!